# AngularJs With Electron Close Application Clear All localStorage

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have create one application AngularJS & Electron

User Login successfully login i have set local Storage
screen redirect to listing  page.

then i application close and again running app but not login screen display, listing page display

application close all localStorage remove

[image]

main.js

```
mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Local Storge

User Login Successfully set localStorge

```
 localStorage.setItem('username', user.username);
 localStorage.setItem('password', user.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing the application? If you are terminating the application from the terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) losing `localStorage` is the expected behaviour. Make sure you are not terminating the app, but closing it with the UI or the proper shortcut. LocalStorage consolidates the storage when the app closes. If you want a storage that works in some other way you can take a look at LevelDB or IndexedDB or any of the libraries that depend on these backends like PouchDB or Dexie DB.

This is the issue where the localStorage bug is discussed https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1731

Comment: terminal (ctrl+c) losing localStorage - how to ?

Comment: If you open your app from the terminal (like we all do when developing in Electron) then it's very common to close it from the terminal, like using the ctrl+c shortcut. If you do it that way it's very likely you will loose what's stored in localStorage. How are you closing the app when you loose the data?

Comment: Attach images how to close

Comment: @LaljiTadhani And when you click there, internally, what method are you using? Are you calling `app.quit()` Can you also share the code you are using to store? Can you read the data from localStorage right after you saved it?

Comment: hi i have change local to session storage problem fix

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. What I did is I just localStorage.removeItem('token'); on initialize electron. Then the token is gone, the app redirects me to login page.

angularjs:

> $onInit = function () {
>           localStorage.removeItem('token'); }

angular4/5:
app.component.ts

> ngOnInit(): void {
>       localStorage.removeItem('token');   }

Comment: application ctrl+5 then what is result, app redirect to login page or stay on same page ?